# Why is my Mongoose User import invalid? Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable

Tags: javascript, node.js, mongoose

My User.js

```
const mongoose = require('mongoose');
const joigoose = require("joigoose")(mongoose);
const { Joi } = require('celebrate');


var joiUserSchema = Joi.object({
    body: Joi.object().keys({
        username: Joi.string().required(),
        name: Joi.string().required(),
        email: Joi.string().email().required(),
        role: Joi.string().default('admin')
      }), 
      query: {
        token: Joi.string().token().required()
    }
});

var mongooseUserSchema = new mongoose.Schema(joigoose.convert(joiUserSchema));
User = mongoose.model('User', mongooseUserSchema);

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', mongooseUserSchema);
module.exports = joiUserSchema;
```

In my index.js

```
const {User, joiUserSchema} = require('./User');
console.log(User);
console.log(joiUserSchema);
```

Both are `undefined` in terminal.
If I try REPL

```
> const {User} = require('./User');
Uncaught TypeError: Assignment to constant variable.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/milenko/pract/joi1/User.js:19:6)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1251:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:1272:10)
```

How to debug this? I want to extend User validation model.

Comment: Don't do `User = mongoose.model('User', mongooseUserSchema);` (although something is weird with the scope here)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second one of these lines overwrites the effect of the first:

```
module.exports = mongoose.model('User', mongooseUserSchema);
module.exports = joiUserSchema;
```

You're trying to make *both* of them the one export from the module.

Your import is trying to use properties of an exported object. To match the import, the export should export an object with those named properties:

```
module.exports = {
    User: mongoose.model('User', mongooseUserSchema),
    joiUserSchema
};
```